# JavaFX Progress Dialog On Saving

Tags: multithreading, javafx, progress-bar

At one point in my application, I have to save a JavaFX UI which takes a long time. During this save, I have to show a Progress Dialog telling the user what is happening at that time.

I have read that heavy tasks should be ran using a Task and not the JavaFX thread. However, this is not possible for me for the 2 following reasons:

1- The heavy tasks include JavaFX confirmation dialog popups which are sometimes buggy on MAC if not called by the JavaFX thread.

2- The save method must return a boolean to tell if the save went ok or not. And this save method is triggered by the JavaFX thread. Meaning the JavaFX thread must return the boolean variable and has to wait for the Task to finish before doing that.

And sadly the JavaFX UI is integrated in a Swing UI which makes it more difficult to work with.

Comment: "The heavy tasks include JavaFX confirmation dialog popups which are sometimes buggy on MAC if not called by the JavaFX thread". The dialogs *must* be shown on the FX Application Thread, no matter what platform you run on. This does not preclude you from running the background work on another thread, though. For 2. use a `Task<Boolean>` and use the `setOnSucceeded` handler to process the result.

Answer (score 0):

[`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) is just one implementation of the [`javafx.concurrent.Worker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) interface, which provides facilities to communicate with the GUI respectively the JavaFX thread. Other implementations are [`Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) and [`ScheduledService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html). Basically, the difference is that `Service` is designed for reuse, whereas `Task` isn't, and `ScheduledService` can restart itself after execution.

So, to address your two concerns:

> The heavy tasks include JavaFX confirmation dialog popups which are sometimes buggy on MAC if not called by the JavaFX thread.

As mentioned before, the `Worker` interface provides a nice API to update the GUI from another thread. For instance, from the JavaFX thread, you can easily bind a [`Labeled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html) to the `message` property which gets updated from the background thread.

> The save method must return a boolean to tell if the save went ok or not. And this save method is triggered by the JavaFX thread. Meaning the JavaFX thread must return the boolean variable and has to wait for the Task to finish before doing that.

For example, `Task`'s `call()` method can return arbitrary objects, which includes `Boolean`. Moreover, the `Worker` interface has a `getValue()` method to retrieve the result from the corresponding worker.

I recommend reading the ["Concurrency in JavaFX" tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_concurrency.htm) for further information. For [`ProgressBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressBar.html) itself, have a look at the ["Progress Bar and Progress Indicator" tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/progress.htm).